# Django: fetch part of url as variable

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

My urls.py look like this

```
...
url(r'^', 'homepage.views.home', name='home'),
...
```

Now if I type in an url like http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx I want that 'xxxxx' to be written in a variable that I can use in views.py . How can I manage to do this?

Comment: It's all in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/). Have you read ?

Comment: It took me some hours of reading and trying out to figure it  out. Now it works fine.

Comment: Cool ... Glad you make it ...! And Don't forget to answer your questions. Sometime you will get good reward ...

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it. Pretty easy, when you know it. A bit confusing, when you're into Django for 3 days as I am. Thanks.

urls.py

```
url(r'^'/(?P<var1>\w+)/$, 'homepage.views.home', name='home')
```

views.py

```
def home(request, var1):
#...
```